# Update time based on previous records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following set of records:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| ID  | DateTimeValue       | UsedMinutes  |
| 1   | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 30           |
| 2   | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 45           |
| 3   | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 20           |
| 4   | 2016-02-02 00:00:00 | 30           |
| 5   | 2016-02-02 00:00:00 | 60           |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to transform them to:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| ID  | DateTimeValue       | UsedMinutes  |
| 1   | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 30           |
| 2   | 2016-01-01 00:30:00 | 45           |
| 3   | 2016-01-01 01:15:00 | 20           |
| 4   | 2016-02-02 00:00:00 | 30           |
| 5   | 2016-02-02 00:30:00 | 60           |
+------------------------------------------+
```

So per date, the time value should be incremented based on the previous record and its 'Used minutes' field. My actual record set has thousands of records, so manually modifying is not an option.

Is it possible to do this with a (single) MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
t.ID,
t.expectedTime,
t.usedMin
FROM 
(
   SELECT
        ID,
        IF(@currentDateTime <> DateTimeValue, @runningTime :='0000-00-00 00:00:00' , 1) resetting,
        IF(@runningTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DateTimeValue, @runningTime) AS expectedTime,
        @minuteToAddNext := UsedMinutes AS usedMin,
        @currentDateTime := DateTimeValue AS previousDateTime,
        @runningTime := IF(@runningTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DateTimeValue + INTERVAL UsedMinutes MINUTE , @runningTime + INTERVAL UsedMinutes MINUTE) AS nextRowsValue
    FROM
            datetimetable
    CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
                    @currentDateTime := '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                    @minuteToAddNext := 0,
                    @runningTime := '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ) AS var
    ORDER BY DateTimeValue
) AS t;
```

<s><kbd>[**<s>WORKING DEMO</s>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d51a/1/0)</kbd> *outputs 4 columns(one extra)*</s>

<kbd>[**UPDATED WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d51a/5/0)</kbd> *outputs 3 columns to match your requirement*

---

**Explanation:**

While scanning each row store the `UsedMinutes` value in a variable called `@minuteToAddNext` like in the query:

`@minuteToAddNext := UsedMinutes`

While scanning the next row your first task is to add the `@minuteToAddNext` value to the `DateTimeValue` only if the `@minuteToAddNext` value was saved from the same `dateTimeValue`. This is translated in the query like this:

`DateTimeValue + INTERVAL IF(@currentDateTime = DateTimeValue, @minuteToAddNext , 0) MINUTE AS updatedDteTimeValue`

Look, if the previous row's `@currentDateTime = current row's DateTimeValue` then you will get `@minuteToAddNext` from `IF`. (Means same `dateTimeValue`).

Otherwise `IF` will return `0`. So, `DateTimeValue + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE = DateTimeValue`

**EDIT:**

In order to update the table with those generated `datetime` values from the above select query you need to run the following query:

```
UPDATE datetimetable DT 
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT
        ID,
        IF(@currentDateTime <> DateTimeValue, @runningTime :='0000-00-00 00:00:00' , 1) resetting,
        IF(@runningTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DateTimeValue, @runningTime) AS expectedTime,
        @minuteToAddNext := UsedMinutes AS usedMin,
        @currentDateTime := DateTimeValue AS previousDateTime,
        @runningTime := IF(@runningTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DateTimeValue + INTERVAL UsedMinutes MINUTE , @runningTime + INTERVAL UsedMinutes MINUTE) AS nextRowsValue
    FROM
            datetimetable
    CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
                    @currentDateTime := '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                    @minuteToAddNext := 0,
                    @runningTime := '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ) AS var
    ORDER BY DateTimeValue
) AS t
ON DT.ID = t.ID 
SET DT.DateTimeValue = t.expectedTime;
```

Comment: Nearly perfect :) But the row with ID 3 is not getting the expected value from my example. That one should take the value from ID 2 and add its minutes. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you want cumulative timevalue for each date.
Corrected now. Please check. @MartindeRuiter

Comment: Looks good! Do you know how this can be made into an update-query, so the values in the table will be updated with the new datetime values?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem

```
mysql> select * from TRE;
+------+---------------+-------------+
| ID   | DateTimeValue | UsedMinutes |
+------+---------------+-------------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01    |          30 |
|    2 | 2016-01-01    |          45 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01    |          20 |
|    4 | 2016-02-02    |          30 |
|    5 | 2016-02-02    |          60 |
+------+---------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select TRE.*,@curRank := @curRank + UsedMinutes as SUM_time from TRE,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY ID;
+------+---------------+-------------+----------+
| ID   | DateTimeValue | UsedMinutes | SUM_time |
+------+---------------+-------------+----------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01    |          30 |       30 |
|    2 | 2016-01-01    |          45 |       75 |
|    3 | 2016-01-01    |          20 |       95 |
|    4 | 2016-02-02    |          30 |      125 |
|    5 | 2016-02-02    |          60 |      185 |
+------+---------------+-------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select DATE_ADD(DateTimeValue, INTERVAL @curRank := @curRank + UsedMinutes MINUTE) from TRE,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY ID;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(DateTimeValue, INTERVAL @curRank := @curRank + UsedMinutes MINUTE) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-01-01 00:30:00                                                         |
| 2016-01-01 01:15:00                                                         |
| 2016-01-01 01:35:00                                                         |
| 2016-02-02 02:05:00                                                         |
| 2016-02-02 03:05:00                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: just added a way to show how to do it if it not much clear let me know

Comment: It should take into account the date, so each new date starts at 00:00:00 hours. See my example table. Any idea's for that requirement? Also, how to update the table with your SQL?

Comment: yes sure in that case add if statement and if new data set curRank=0 then you will get what you want

Comment: how can it be made into an update query to update the datetime values in the original table?